# Unit Testing - test deletion of archived files

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I am writing unit test for this function -

```
public void DeleteExpiredArchiveFiles(string directory, int daysInArchive)
{
    //Delete files from the directory which are older than parameter - daysInArchive
}
```

I need to access some sample files in the code for this unit test.
What is the correct approach -
- Add sample files in the Unit Test project and set them to 'Copy to output directory' or
- Add sample files to some location like on C:\SampleFiles folder

I prefer first approach here, so any other developer running these tests, do not have to copy files to correct folder before running unit tests.

Any comments - Is there any other better approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you test against FS Mock?

Comment: Where is the code to be reviewed?

Answer (score 1):

You should  create the files in the test setup.
Creating  and deleting files in the file system takes some time. Using some FS mock / fake will make the test run much faster.